# Any way to get sudo privleges without opening a command line in raspian?

Tags: raspbian, python, sudo

Right now to get python scripts to run with user privleges in thonny with typing in this command from the command line:

sudo thonny

I can't close the command window without it closing thonny also

Is there any way to modify the shortcut in the raspian OS to automatically give super user privileges to thonny? (otherwise it can't even save files or allow python scripts to save files either)

Comment: why does thonny need super user privileges?

Comment: I don't know why you would WANT to run Thonny with root privileges. Generally interpreted code does not for security reasons. There is a desktop entry which executes `/usr/bin/thonny %F`. You could TRY including sudo in this. Previously there was a `gksudo` command but this is deprecated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66413801/can-thonny-run-scripts-as-root-on-raspberry-pi asked and answered on stackoverflow apparently

Comment: this is not a Raspberry Pi specific question

Comment: gksudo was replaced with gksu which I think has similar functionality including sudo support.

Comment: @bravo the reason is in the question... But I'll post it again. Thonny can't write files from scripts or save files, what use is an ide if it can't even save a file?. I don't mind giving lots of rights to programs, I just want them to work

Comment: @jsotola This is about Raspbian, which only runs on a pi (as far as I'm aware)

Comment: @user10489 is there any way to get the Raspbian gui  shortcut to run gsku it does it have to be ran from from the command prompt? What use is a gui if you can only use the prompt to run programs?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  You ask how to run it with sudo when you really need to fix it so that it can write files as a normal user.

Comment: I would imagine since thonny is installed by default, that the raspberrypi foundation would've have made it so that it works for (at least) the `pi` user ... are you running as that user, of have you created a new user?

Comment: It doesn't work for the pi user and people have complained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo thonny
```

in a file on your desktop, and set the executable permissions on it. Then you can simply double click it and select "Execute" in the dialog that opens.

In your particular use case, you might want to rethink where you store the Python files so that changing them wouldn't require `sudo`. E.g. you could create `/home/pi/bin` and add it to your PATH, or give the `pi` user write access to `/usr/local/bin` and store your Python scripts there.

Comment: You may want to use `sudo -H thonny`. [See what does sudo -H do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623025/what-does-sudo-h-do) for why you want that. Basically without the -H if you make any config changes while running `thonny` in `sudo` mode, the config files will be overwritten by `root`. After that the normal user, say `pi` won't have write access to its own config files!

Comment: @user68186 I suppose the OP already has these files owned by root, because they were running the exact same command from the terminal.

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the shortcut to this:

And it gives thonny super user privileges from the gui

[image]

```
sudo -H /usr/bin/thonny %F
```